# NSTimeInterval 15mins before

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have one variable **startDate** which is in NSTimeInterval.

How can I get NSTimeInterval just 15mins before to actual startDate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval reqStartDate = startDate - (15*60);
```